# Download application/PDF with Node.js

Tags: node.js, blob

I'm receiving a file with the headers below from outbound API
[image]

And the content looks like below
[image]

For some how and not able to save such a file in my temp dir. The file looks wrong after save.
This there a way to save it in the right way.

```
 axios.get(process.env.SOZLESME_IMZA_API + '/downloadfile?SignerId=' + req.body.SignerId + '&FileKey=' + req.body.FileKey,
await getHeaders())
    .then(response => {
 // save here      
 
  //      helper.sendResult(res, response.data, null, req);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        helper.sendResult(res, null, err, req);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should 'downloadjs' node module to download a pdf file.

```
const download = require('downloadjs');

...

    const specificationId = this.$route.params.specificationId;

    axios
        .get(process.env.SOZLESME_IMZA_API + '/downloadfile?SignerId=' + req.body.SignerId + '&FileKey=' + req.body.FileKey, {
            headers: await getHeaders(),
            responseType: 'blob', // browser only option
        })
        .then(response => {
           const content = response.headers['content-type'];
           download(response.data, file_name, content);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));

...
```

Comment: this did not work for me. downloadjs is a client-side script and won't work with nodejs when it is used as a back-end.